# window.location.href is Redirecting but not getting URL

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, window

CODE

```
<script>
  window.location.href = 'SomeSite.php';   // THIS WORKS
  var x = window.location.href;            // THIS DOES NOT!  
  alert("X : ",x);                         // Shows X : 
</script>
```

I have no function or Anything. I just run this Script Code in my HTML File and it used to work for Months.
I have no idea why it isn't working right now. How is it that Im able to redirect the page using **window.location.href** but not get the current URL?

Comment: alert("X : "+x);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `alert("X : ",x);` Try using `alert("X : " + x);`. This should solve it. When you put a comma inside the alert function, it might consider it as another parameter, so you must concatenate using "+".

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I use a lot of languages and the Print statement in every language is either + or , so gt confused.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a comma you need to use a `+` to properly concatenate the two values together, this is just joining the `x` variable to the print.

If you were to print out `x` by itself you would get the value, but in your context the incorrect concatenation was the issue.

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I use a lot of languages and the Print statement in every language is either + or , so gt confused.

Answer (score 0):

To append a string to another one in javascript, you should use the `+` operator. You cannot use a comma. Put it only when you're using a function that requires multiple parameters.
Because here, `alert()` thought that you're putting a second parameter!
For example:

```
let string1 = "Hello, "; //Define the first variable.
let string2 = "world!";  //And the second one.

alert(string1 + string2);//Show a message and join the two strings together!
```

Here you can use the comma:

```
<script>
   let string = "We hate the earth!";
   string = string.replace("hate", "love"); //FYI: replace() is used to replace a sequence of characters by an another.
</script>
```

So your code should be:

```
<script>
  var x = window.location.href;
  alert("X : " + x);           //Join "X : " and x together!
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed `var` to `const`.
See other answers regarding concatenation. Changed to template literals.

```
<script>
    // window.location.href = 'SomeSite.php'; // THIS WORKS
    alert(window.location.href);
    const x = window.location.href;
    alert(`x: ${x}`)
</script>
```